# SSL webservice call using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl

I have to call a HTTPS web service on my VPN & I have .cert & security jars with me. How to import the cert file & where to place it. I am using WMB Toolkit  tried placing them in WMB jdk/jre/lib/security but it is noy working

TIA..!

Comment: What is WMB? You have to put the certificate into a Java key store and load it in your program.

Comment: WMB stands for IBM Web Message Broker.It is an ISB , toolkit is similar to RAD or eclipse.

Comment: Just do what it says in the JSSE Reference Guide in the JDK documentation. If the server certificate is signed there's nothing you have to do at all except use an HTTPS: URL.